# Run a pod without scheduler in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I searched the documentation but I am unable to find out if I can run a pod in Kubernetes without Scheduler. If anyone can help with any pointers it would be helpful

Update:
I can attach a label to node and let pod stick to that label but that would involve going through the scheduler. Is there any method without daemonset and does not use scheduler.

Comment: Are you looking for [kubectl run](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.7/#run)?

Comment: Actually I thought of it being from yaml file

Answer (score 12):

The scheduler just sets the spec.nodeName field on the pod. You can set that to a node name yourself if you know which node you want to run your pod, though you are then responsible for ensuring the node has sufficient resources to run the pod (enough memory, free host ports, etc… all things the scheduler is normally responsible for checking before it assigns a pod to a node)

Comment: Ok I need to test this(setting the nodename)  without running the scheduler.

Comment: Note that kubelet may still prevent the pod from running due to unavailable Extended Resources. eg status `OutOfexample.com/foo` https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/extended-resource/

Comment: This question is listed in the CKA Curriculum for the kubernetes exam, and it looks like this is the intended answer.

Answer (score 5):

You want [static pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/static-pod/)

> Static pods are managed directly by kubelet daemon on a specific node, without API server observing it. It does not have associated any replication controller, kubelet daemon itself watches it and restarts it when it crashes.

Comment: I think so static pods is replaced by daemonset and it runs on all nodes. I was looking for running a pod without the use of scheduler. So I can attach a label to node and let pod stick to that label but that would involve a scheduler. Is there any method without daemonset and does not use scheduler

Comment: DeamonSet is for Pods you want to run on all nodes (or a group of nodes). It requires a scheduler. Static Pods are meant for running stuff before the scheduler is available (for example, the scheduler itself)

Comment: Yes that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a `nodeName` attribute to the pod definition which by they normally field out by the scheduler therefor it's not a mandatory field.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  -  image: nginx
     name: nginx
  nodeName: node01
```

if the pod has been created and in pending state you have to recreate it with the new field, edit is not permitted with the nodeName att.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers given here would require a scheduler to run.

I think what you want to do is create the manifest file of the pod and put it in the default manifest directory of the node in question.

Default directory is /etc/kubernetes/manifests/

The pod will automatically be created and if you wish to delete it, just delete the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a **nodeName** attribute to the pod definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  nodeName: controlplane
  containers:
  -  image: nginx
     name: nginx
```

Now important point - check the node listed by using below command, and then assign to one of them:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this out to yourself very easy in your lab

```
kubectl run static-pod --image=nginx --dry-run=client -o yaml > static-pod.yaml
sudo mv /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml /etc/kubernetes/
# make sure scheduler is gone
sudo crictl ps | grep -i sched 
sudo cp static-pod.yaml /etc/kubernetes/manifests/
kubectl get pods static-pod-cp1 # my controlpoint is called cp1
# Put the scheduler back 
sudo mv /etc/kubernetes/kube-scheduler.yaml /etc/kubernetes/manifests/
```

Since the pod was running and you had no scheduler, it's true that static pods do not use a scheduler.